# Conditionally add a new column in conjunction with UNION ALL in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am combining two tables that have the same columns. They are from two different sources, like treatment and control groups. I want to know where each row came from.

Is it possible to do so by modifying my query somehow?

```
--Combine them
create table x as (
select * from y
union all
select * from z);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add another column to identify the source?

```
CREATE TABLE x AS 
SELECT 'y' src, * FROM y
UNION ALL
SELECT 'z' src, * FROM z;
```

Comment: This is great. Sorry that I didn't know something so basic.